# How create a usable data object

Tags: swift, swiftui, swifty-json

I have swiftyJSON added as a package dependancy and have the appropriate import statement.

My JSON file has the following format:

```
    "00AK": {
        "icao": "00AK",
        "iata": "",
        "name": "Lowell Field",
        "city": "Anchor Point",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "country": "US",
        "elevation": 450,
        "lat": 59.94919968,
        "lon": -151.695999146,
        "tz": "America\/Anchorage"
    },
    "00AL": {
        "icao": "00AL",
        "iata": "",
        "name": "Epps Airpark",
        "city": "Harvest",
        "state": "Alabama",
        "country": "US",
        "elevation": 820,
        "lat": 34.8647994995,
        "lon": -86.7703018188,
        "tz": "America\/Chicago"
```

etc. And the JSON file is stored within the app bundle

This is the code I have currently:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftyJSON
let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airports", withExtension: "json")
let jsonString = try? String(contentsOf: path!)
let dataFromString = jsonString!.data
let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
```

This gives me the error on the last line of....

"Cannot convert value of type ' (String.Encoding, Bool) -> Data?' to expected argument type 'Data'"

If I 'mouseover' the jsonString var the tooltip shows me the correct string from the file, but I don't understand why the next bit just isn't working.

Comment: Why do you need SwiftyJSON? You could just use Decodable/ Encodable.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I was just looking at that now - I'm not sure I understand (yet) how to handle a JSON file formatted like in the example I gave with nested levels... (sorry if that's not the correct term)

Comment: Your case is not very straightforward. This can help you: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/customizing-codable-types-in-swift/ get over the custom keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be related to convert to Data, this is how I would read the file and convert to Data

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airports", withExtension: "json")!
let jsonString = try! String(contentsOf: url)
let dataFromString = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
```

To move on here is a simplified example how you can use `Codable` for your json

```
struct Airport: Codable {
    let icao: String
    let name: String
    let city: String
    let country: String
    let elevation: Int
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "lat"
        case longitude = "lon"
        case icao, name, city, country, elevation
    }
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Airport].self, from: dataFromString)
    let airports = result.values
    print(airports)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note that I did not include all fields here and also made some assumptions what the file content looked like since you have only included a part of it.